# Users' ids are shoved instead of their mentions when listed using discord bot

Tags: javascript, caching, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot which should be able list eg. all users in the guild everytime, when `/members` command is used. The following code snipped is how I handle this command:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    const { commandName } = interaction;

    if (commandName === 'members') {
        const members = await interaction.guild.members.fetch();
        const membersList = Array.from(members.values());

        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [{
            description: members.join(', ')
        }] });
    }
});
```

It works, all users are listed and separated by comma. However, most of users  are displayed with their IDs instead of names, eg. `<@123456798123456>` instead of `@Michal`.

Why is this happening? Are these users not cached? I thought `members.fetch()` will cache all the users. Is there any way how can I fix it (I would prefer display users' mentions instead of their names in plain text)?

Comment: if you want to @ someone through their name, you need to reply with `<@1234213>` (with < > ). Then it will resolve to `@Michal` in the text-channel

Comment: Did it work for you? or do you need more help?

Comment: @Joel Thank you for your reply. However, the problem is still same. In my snipped, I used `GuildMember.toString` method (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=toString), so I think `<@{member.id}>`, `member.toString()` and `member` are same, all of them just print user mention.

Comment: Could it possibly be an issue with your app client? Try closing and re-opening Discord or viewing the message on another device

Comment: Maybe something to do with your permissions a.k.a. intents? Alternatively, try pinging the user like so: `<@!${interaction.member.id}>` with the `!`

Comment: Or maybe try the `followUp` method. `interaction.followUp({content: \`<@!${interaction.member.id}>\`, embeds: []})`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// CJS
const userMention = require('discord.js');
// ES6
import userMention from 'discord.js';
// ...
interaction.reply(userMention(<User>.id));
// https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/main/function/userMention
// returns a string with the mention of the user
```

The [builders](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/main/general/welcome) have lots of similar useful functions.